# How do classes get instantiated by the Router?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I am changing the required arguments for the __construct() method of a Controller class. After adding the arguments to the class constructor, no page will load that uses that controller.

This is an application for which there is little documentation and I'm just recently hired to work on it. I am an experienced developer, but was thrown onto a Symfony project, with which I've never worked.

My issue, simply stated, is that I need to use a configuration option that is originally loaded from a Docker container configuration, into a Symfony class. Lead developers insist that this configuration be injected into the class. Ok, fine.

But when I add the additional arguments to the __construct() method, I start getting errors, which I also would expect. But I have no idea where to look to find the instantiation call?

Here is the beginning of the Class definition, which shows the construct method with three new arguments tacked onto the end:

```
class DocTreeController extends AbstractController
{
    use CommandDispatcherTrait;

    private const ETAG_SEED = '1';

    /**
     * @var ClientInterface
     */
    private $guzzleJsonClient;

    private $caseNetworkSecret;
    private $caseNetworkScope;
    private $caseTokenServer;

    /**
     * @var PdoAdapter
     */
    private $externalDocCache;

    public function __construct(ClientInterface $guzzleJsonClient, PdoAdapter $externalDocCache, ?string $caseNetworkSecret, ?string $caseNetworkScope, ?string $caseTokenServer)
    {
        $this->guzzleJsonClient = $guzzleJsonClient;
        $this->externalDocCache = $externalDocCache;
        $this->caseNetworkSecret = $caseNetworkSecret;
        $this->caseTokenServer = $caseTokenServer;
        $this->caseNetworkScope = $caseNetworkScope;
    }
```

Here is an abbreviated version of what is the index function, according to the Routes applied to it in the comments:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/doc/{slug}.{_format}", name="doc_tree_view", methods={"GET"}, defaults={"_format"="html", "lsItemId"=null})
     * @Route("/doc/{slug}/av.{_format}", name="doc_tree_view_av", methods={"GET"}, defaults={"_format"="html", "lsItemId"=null})
     * @Route("/doc/{slug}/lv.{_format}", name="doc_tree_view_log", methods={"GET"}, defaults={"_format"="html", "lsItemId"=null})
     * @Route("/doc/{slug}/{assocGroup}.{_format}", name="doc_tree_view_ag", methods={"GET"}, defaults={"_format"="html", "lsItemId"=null})
     * @Entity("lsDoc", expr="repository.findOneBySlug(slug)")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function viewAction(LsDoc $lsDoc, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authChecker, ?UserInterface $user = null, $_format = 'html', $lsItemId = null, $assocGroup = null)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        ....

        return $ret;
    }
```

And based on some super-ineffective stumbling around in Symfony documentation, here is an entry I tried to make in the services.yaml file, thinking this must be a service, somehow:

```
    # Doc Controller
    App\Controller\Framework\DocTreeController:
        class: App\Controller\Framework\DocTreeController
        arguments:
            $guzzleJsonClient: '@csa_guzzle.client.json'
            $externalDocCache: '@salt.cache.external_docs'
            $caseNetworkSecret: '%case_network_secret%'
            $caseNetworkScope: '%case_network_scope%'
            $caseTokenServer: '%case_token_server%'
```

When I even go to the index, I get the following error message:

```
[2019-05-24 20:00:37] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception ArgumentCountError: "Too few arguments to function App\Controller\Framework\DocTreeController::__construct(), 2 passed in /var/www/html/var/cache/prod/ContainerAcbnxwG/getDocTreeControllerService.php on line 14 and exactly 5 expected" at /var/www/html/src/Controller/Framework/DocTreeController.php line 58 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Too few arguments to function App\\Controller\\Framework\\DocTreeController::__construct(), 2 passed in /var/www/html/var/cache/prod/ContainerAcbnxwG/getDocTreeControllerService.php on line 14 and exactly 5 expected at /var/www/html/src/Controller/Framework/DocTreeController.php:58)"} []
```

What frustrates me is that the error message points to what appears to be a dynamically-generated cache file, not an actual document in the framework.

Appreciate any help folks here are good enough to leave!

Comment: Probably won't help in this case, but sometimes these things are resolved by clearing the cache. From a command line, `bin/console cache:clear`.

Comment: Symfony version?  Is there a _defaults section in services.yaml and does it have autowire and autoconfigure set to true? And is there a controller section for setting the controller.service_arguments tag?

Comment: To address your question, the [kernel docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#resolve-the-controller) discuss how controllers are resolved.  The controller itself will be pulled from [the container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html) when everything is wired correctly.  The fact that two arguments are injected implies that the basic wiring is okay.  As previously noted, it is possible that all you need to do is to insure the cache gets rebuilt.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. All of them are helpful. In the end, @ehymel had the right answer, and I needed to clear the caches out. But the other guidance has been invaluable for learning this new system.